# nohup and screen not working when running program in background?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I don't why but my `screen` command running on server is stopping on its own. Therefore I tried to use `nohup`. e.g:

```
nohup bzcat a.bz
```

But when running `nohup` it is giving me

```
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
```

Also in order to resume I run: `fg` which gives me:

```
-bash: fg: current: no such job
```

Answer (score 0):

The message from `nohup` is perfectly ok. It's just explaining what it's doing. When you run a program with nohup, it no longer uses what you type on the terminal, nor it outputs anything on the terminal. `nohup` redirects the output of the program to a file called `nohup.out`.

And it's very different to `nohup` a program from running it in background (running in background would be `bzcat a.bz &`). When a program runs in the background, it does ignore the input from the terminal (only the program running in foreground can use what you type in the terminal, that's why it's called "foreground" process, because it's the one you're actually interacting with) but it does output to the terminal. It's possible to run a program both in nohup mode and in the background. In fact, it's usually the way `nohup` is used. If you `nohup` a program but doesn't launch it in the background, you can't call `fg` on it because it's actually not backgrounded. It just doesn't output to the terminal.

`nohup` allows you to run a program in a mode in which it will ignore `HUP` signals. Terminals tipically send `HUP` signals when you close the terminal. So a program running in background in nohup mode will not stop when you close the terminal in which you launched it.